# Buttons: HTML/SCSS line breaks

Tags: html, css, angular, button

I'm training on Angular and therefore solid HTML and SCSS skills are recommended, but I have a slight problem. Here's my view, with 3 buttons, I'd like the first two to be on the same line and the last one (the purple one) to be below. Everything I've tried hasn't worked, so how do I go about it?

[Here's my view to help you understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge0Fv.png)

Here is my HTML:

```
<mat-card-actions>
      <mat-spinner *ngIf="loading$ | async; else buttons"></mat-spinner>
      <ng-template #buttons>
        <div class="action-buttons">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onHire()">EMBAUCHER</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="onRefuse()">REFUSER</button>
        </div>
        <div class="back-button">
          <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="onGoBack()" class="return-button">RETOUR</button>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
</mat-card-actions>
```

And here's my CSS that I've already been able to realize:

```
  button {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }

.action-buttons {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: block;
}

  .back-button {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Thank you in advance if you take the time to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

I have added button-section class in div also written style for that class

```css
button {
margin: 10px!important;
}
.button-section{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<mat-card-actions>
      <mat-spinner *ngIf="loading$ | async; else buttons"></mat-spinner>
      <ng-template #buttons>
      <div class="button-section">
        <div class="action-buttons">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onHire()">EMBAUCHER</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="onRefuse()">REFUSER</button>
        </div>
        <div class="back-button">
          <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="onGoBack()" class="btn btn-light">RETOUR</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
</mat-card-actions>
```

Comment: a brief explanation: a mat-card-action has by defect a class: `mat-mdc-card-actions mdc-card__actions`. this class have a `display:flex, direction:row` this makes that all child (but not all the chil of child) are distributed in a "row". Really you can simply enclosed all in a div without any class